# How to send mails to users with bulk operations in drupal7

Tags: 7, emails, views

I want to select some users from a view with the field VBO , and to send to this users an email which cotaining a subject and a body. How can I proceed?

---

Thanks for the response.
I'm a new user of drupal and my authenticated user have to send a mail for selected user with VBO, and have to enter the contents of mail. (subject + body). After confirmation the system send to selected users the mail.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Rules module with VBO to extend the operations of VBO. In Rules module, you can select the action to send mails to users with whatever text you want.

Comment: I'm trying to use Views send